# CRUD operations on Redshift databases using Golang

Tags: go, crud, amazon-redshift

Could you please give me some explanations and some code examples on how it would be done (ex: creating tables and inserting data) ?
Which library would you advise me to use ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Please note the side-effect import of ***github.com/lib/pq***
- After this queries can be run by db.Query() or db.Exec()
- https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#example_DB_Query
- https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#pkg-examples

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func MakeRedshfitConnection(username, password, host, port, dbName string) (*sql.DB, error) {

    url := fmt.Sprintf("sslmode=require user=%v password=%v host=%v port=%v dbname=%v",
        username,
        password,
        host,
        port,
        dbName)

    var err error
    var db *sql.DB
    if db, err = sql.Open("postgres", url); err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("redshift conn error : (%v)", err)
    }

    if err = db.Ping(); err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("redshift ping error : (%v)", err)
    }
    return db, nil
}
```

Comment: There is a minor syntax error in the first return statement. I couldn't fix it because StackOverflow requires an edit of a minimal 6 chars.

Closing bracket in fmt.Errorf should be after `err`.